# Debug as Blackberry Device + Socket connection

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am debugging the Blackberry application using Eclipse -> Debug as -> Blackberry device

Whenever I try to establish socket connection with the server in LAN , I get `IOException` and I am not able to connect to LAN server through real device.

I am using Blackberry Pearl 8100 device.

Answer (score 1):

Based on further comments and discussion, I think this is a better answer:

A BlackBerry device will only automatically route a network connection through the USB port (and so to the local LAN) if the device is activated on a BES.

If the device is a non-BES device, you require special code to do a USB connection - i.e. if you're plugged into USB your device will still attempt to use its radio to make the network connection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the blackberry mds simulator - then you can get network connections.

NB. When you have a production version of your app: you should note that not all blackberry devices will allow network connections - it will depend on which servers they use.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about managing MDS? You can download it from the blackberry developer site - then install it - then you run it in the background. For production code on real devices - just beware of the problem - as I don't know your situation it may not be a problem for you. A single app on a single device - unlikely to be a problem - a commerical app on many devices - you will likely need a partnership with RIM to get it approved to work on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

I need a bit more information - the message in the IOException is important - it'll have some information about why the connection failed.

Assuming that your device is connected to a BES, and has a data plan, you should be able to connect to a server on your LAN.  Do you know if your device has any connectivity issues? Can you test a connection to the same server using the BlackBerry Browser?  It may also have to do with IT Policies on the BES.

Comment: First of all,I dont know the stack trace of exception is not printed on the console.I get "no stack trace".
Secondly,I have a full fledge functioning device with good data plan.
I connect the device to computer usb port,the simulator allows me to establish connection to another pc in network having LAN ip(not a public ip)
If I connect BB device thru usb,I should be able to connect to same n/w,I guess...which I coudn't...

Comment: Ok - I understand the problem I think.  I've posted another answer that should be a better fit.